# JavaScript execute function after pressing Enter

Tags: javascript, onclick

I wanted to know how its possible to call a javascript function , as soon as one presses the "return(enter" key,just as in chat systems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.onkeypress = function(e)
{
 switch(e.keyCode e.which) //[2]
 {
  case NUMPAD_ENTER_KEY_CODE: //[1]
  case ENTER_KEY_CODE:
   doSomething();
   return false;
  default:
   if (window.console) console.log(e.keyCode e.which); //[2]
   return true;
 }
}
```

this is then expandable to work for any number of key codes.  You can also try the onKeyDown or onKeyUp events.

Remember to replace ENTER_KEY_CODE with the actual key code (32?). This should print out the keyCodes of any keys that are not enter so that you can figure out their keyCodes.

Edit:
[1] I forgot to mention you may want to detect the numpad-enter keycode.
[2] I forgot that onkeypress uses e.which to store the keyCode

Comment: table for keyCode http://www.webonweboff.com/tips/js/event_key_codes.aspx & more on detecting key stroke http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html

Comment: apologies, onkeypress uses e.which.  I'm used to using normalized events in jQuery. onkeydown uses e.keyCode.

Comment: The main problem in IE is that there's no event object passed into the event handler function. You need to use `window.event` in IE.

Answer (score 2):

The following will do what you want reliably in all major browsers. In IE, you need to get the event object via `window.event` because it is not passed in as a parameter to the function. Also, using the character code rather than a key code will mean that all enter keys are automatically detected without needing separate detection for each.

For more information on handling key events in JavaScript, I consider http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html the definitive reference.

```
document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var charCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode == 13) {
        // Insert Enter handling code here
        alert("Enter pressed");
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

**Enter any thing in Text box then press Enter to execute**

```
<form onSubmit='alerttest(this); return false'>        
    <input type="text">         
</form>


<script language="javascript">
    function alerttest()
    {
        alert("Executing jolly.exe !!!!");
        // function edited by Inderpreet singh
    }
</script>
```